# TestNG - @DataProvider annotation not working in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am Using TestNG with Selenium WebDriver. I am trying to get the 'dataprovider' annotation working in my Eclipse IDE. However, after adding the below annotation, Eclipse displays the following errors:

```
  @DataProvider(name = "test1")
  public Object[][] createData1() {
   return new Object[][] {
     { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
     { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
   };
  }
```

ERROR:

Multiple markers at this line:

- Type mismatch: Cannot convert from String to EcmascriptProtos.Object
- Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Integer to EcmascriptProtos.Object

I am using the latest version of TestNG:

6.8.6.20130517

I am using Eclipse Indigo. The weird thing is that on a different machine (My personal laptop), I am running Eclipse Juno, and the @dataprovider annotation works just fine with no issues.

Any Help would be much appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an `import` of `EcmascriptProtos.Object`, remove it. The `Object` returned by the data provider are regular `java.lang.Objects`.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what it was. Don't know how the import got there in the first place, but after removing it, my error disappeared :-)